# Pandas set_index doesn't drop the column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I run the following code function on my dataframe:

```
del dfname["Unnamed: 0"]
dfname["date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfname["date"])
dfname.set_index(dfname["date"], drop=True, inplace=True)
```

But the column does not drop (I know that the default is `drop=True`)

[The output dataframe looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apnc3.jpg). I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: `.set_index()` wants the actual column **name**, so `'date'`, not `dfname["date"]`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Change column of DataFrame to column name, also `drop = True` is default, so is possible remove it:

```
dfname.set_index(dfname["date"], drop = True, inplace = True)
```

to:

```
dfname.set_index("date", inplace = True)
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
dfname = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  

dfname.set_index("date", inplace = True)
print (dfname)
            a
date         
2017-04-03  0
2017-04-04  1
2017-04-05  2
2017-04-06  3
2017-04-07  4
2017-04-08  5
2017-04-09  6
2017-04-10  7
2017-04-11  8
2017-04-12  9
```

EDIT:

If input is file, use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameters `index_col` and `parse_dates` for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=['date'], parse_dates=['date'])
```

Comment: awesome! just the column name did it! THANKS!

Comment: @jezrael, I encountered this today. Never noticed yet. If I use ```df.set_index(df["col_1"])``` this does not drop the column given that drop parameter is set to True by default. If I did the following ```df.set_index("col_1")``` then it drops the columns "col_1". What's that behavior?

Comment: Note that above answer is not same as assigning index. Refer: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13649

Avoid direct column names.